# Call listener by clicking pencil (primefaces 2.2.1 rowEditor)

Tags: java, html, jsf-2, primefaces

How can I call listener after clicking pencil on rowEditor?
I want to prepare text from dataTable for editing (clear html tags for tabs and return carriages). 
Do you have any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: there's an ajax event called "rowEdit", but I'm not sure if it's executed when you click the pencil or when you finish editing the row. did you try it?

Comment: RowEditEvent called when someone finish editing. Do you have any ideas, how i can modify cell data for editing? Thank you.

Comment: In xhtml: <p:dataTable rowEditListener="#{myBean.handleRowEdit}"> and in the bean, public void handleRowEdit(RowEditEvent re)

Answer (score 3):

Actually,there is no event for pencil in datatable.If you want to call listener after pencil click,you can do like that.Wrap rowEditor into commandLink.I did and it works.

```
<p:commandLink id="rowEditLink" action="#{teamMB.initCombo}" ajax="true"
                        update=":formContent:teamTable>

      <p:rowEditor />
 </p:commandLink >
```

Answer (score 3):

*This won't work for version 2.2.1, but it can still be relevant for others*

2 year old question but it's one of the top Google results.

There is a way to do this without using `<p:commandLink>`

The [Primefaces User Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_4_0_edtn2.pdf) on page 154 talks about ajax events. There are three events of interest `rowEdit, rowEditInit, rowEditCancel`.

`rowEditInit` is the event that triggers when a row switches to edit mode
`rowEditCancel` is the event that triggers when a row edit is cancelled

So your code should look like this

```
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{tableBean.onEditInitCleanUp}" update="@form">
```

Then your listener would do the appropriate clean up.

Comment: You should notice version of primefaces in the question !

Comment: Probably you don't need the 'update' param because the <p:rowEdit/> will update the row. In my case the table was in a dialog so if you update it closes and in that case you have to take charge of reopen the dialog again. PS: The ajax solution is quite elegant